App is hidden below the menu bar when maximized
My Ubuntu is configured with a side bar. Therefore when I maximize an app, it should fit the window size up to the side bar.
I don't know how it happened (I didn't have this issue before) but when I maximize an app it extends below the side bar (attached picture). I mean that the side bar becomes half transparent and some of the app goes below the side bar and is hidden.
Is this a bug or some setting issue?
To correct this I need to Restore Down and Maximize the app window.

